# SQL Server response time increasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, service

I'm currently working on updating an ERP called Sage 1000 to a newer version. The main change occurred along the upgrade is that the ERP solution and its database became on two different server. Ever since, The response time has significantly increased.

The part related to SQL Server is the following: whenever the time response problem happens, I restart the SQL Server service and it starts working just fine, at least for a couple of days until I have to restart it again.

Within the task manager before restarting the service I can see that it consumes nearly 17 to 20 gigabytes of memory witch is an insane amount even for a server run service, after restart, the amount of memory drops to a normal 2 to 3 gigabytes.

So my question is the following: in your experience what could be the cause of such abnormal behavior? Right now I created a planned task to restart the service everyday at 3:00 am, but it's not a radical solution.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: To start out, what is the MaxServerMemory set to in the instance's properties?  How much total memory is installed on the Sql Server?

Comment: @rvsc48 the maxservermemory is set on 20Gigabytes and the total memory is installed on the Sql Server is the same

Comment: You should always leave 4 - 6 gb at least for the OS on the Sql Server.  I would either add memory to the Sql Server asap, or, reduce the maxservermemory from 20gb to 14gb (14336mb) and see if things improve.